# How do I link an extracted python-dev config to a virtualenv python installation?

Tags: python, virtualenv, uwsgi, sudo

I am trying to install a python project on a server where I don't have root access.  I've managed to install `virtualenv` and `pip` locally, but the `pip install` is now failing when trying to install `uwsgi` (specifically trying to build `wheel`) with several `error: Python.h: No such file or directory` errors.

From what I've gathered I need to install `python-dev`, but as I don't have sudo access I've had to download and extract the `python-dev` package.

Where I'm stuck now is how to link `python-dev` to the `python` I've installed in my `virtualenv`.

Server details:

```
$ uname -a
4.9.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.210-1 (2020-01-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ python --version
Python 3.5.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, could you ask your admin for help?

OK, let's summarize: `python.h: No such file or directory` looks like the C compiler could not find the necessary header files. Those files are contained in the `python-dev` package, but you are not permitted to install it. You have downloaded the package and extracted its files somewhere.

Now you should set the xx_PATH environment variables that `gcc` uses to find additional library and header files locations, see the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html) and the [example here](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/an_introduction_to_gcc/gccintro_23.html) for details and try the installation again.

Anyway this fixes only the first compilation error.

Comment: I will ask them but they specifically state that no install requiring sudo access will be allowed, so I figured I might as well find a way around it.